# vs_ajax extenstion In fancybox Jquery Issue in magento error is : jQuery(...).fancybox is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, fancybox

vs_ajax extenstion  In fancybox Jquery Issue in magento

It dispaly error

: jQuery(...).fancybox is not a function

onComplete: function(){

What type of issue i can't undestand.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox(
        {
           hideOnContentClick : true,
           width: 382,
           autoDimensions: true,
           type : 'iframe',
           showTitle: false,
           scrolling: 'no',
           onComplete: function(){
            jQuery('#fancybox-frame').load(function() { // wait for frame to load and then gets it's height
                jQuery('#fancybox-content').height(jQuery(this).contents().find('body').height()+30);
                jQuery.fancybox.resize();
             });

           }
        }
    );
});
function showOptions(id){
    jQuery('#fancybox'+id).trigger('click');
}
function setAjaxData(data,iframe){
    if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
        alert(data.message);
    }else{
        if(jQuery('.block-cart')){
            jQuery('.block-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
        }
        if(jQuery('.header .links')){
            jQuery('.header .links').replaceWith(data.toplink);
        }
    jQuery.fancybox.close();
    }
}
function setLocationAjax(url,id){
    url += 'isAjax/1';
    url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajax/index");
    jQuery('#ajax_loader'+id).show();
    try {
        jQuery.ajax( {
            url : url,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                jQuery('#ajax_loader'+id).hide();
                setAjaxData(data,false);           
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```

vs_ajax extenstion  In fancybox Jquery Issue in magento

It dispaly error

: jQuery(...).fancybox is not a function

onComplete: function(){

What type of issue i can't undestand.

Comment: be sure to include required js file for fancybox.

Comment: I am included fancybox jquery. and also check it on view source. it was includeed.

Comment: which jquery and fancybox version you are using???

Comment: jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js is used Fancy box and jquery-1.6.4.min.js used.

Comment: I am geting something. i am see two jquery jquery-1.6.4.min.js and other is jquery-1.11.1.min.js but i am Jquery no.confilict js.

Comment: Any issue of this jquery

Comment: just remove jquery-1.6.4 file..

Comment: show files that you use to include necessary scripts and css...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just see these issues :-

1.) Use appropriate version of jquery file (which jquery version to use just see in documentation of fancy box)

2.) Avoid using multiple versions of same jquery files or avoid including single js file twice.

3.) Just check the order of js files included,first include jquery file and then fancybox js file.

4.) If you are using many jquery files on a page then use `$.noConflict()`(in order to avoid conflict between different js files).

see complete documentation here:-http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: You right i am added  jquery-1.11.1.min.js magento sidebar using xml.  other js install Vs_ajax Extenstion. how can I manage jquery

Comment: @JaydipsinhParmar...just include latest i.e. jquery-1.11.1 min.js file and remove other jquery files with lower versions..

Comment: I am not added Jquery 1.6.4 i am added latest 1.11.1 but it will include with Vs_ajax Extenstion in magento. what i am doing?

Comment: @JaydipsinhParmar...sorry but i have not worked in magneto ...if it is adding jquery-1.6.4 then don't include jquery 1.11.1 because fancybox can work with jquery-1.6.4 also...

Comment: I am reomve jquery 1.11.1 but same error in  

onComplete: function(){ here display error

Comment: plz post in your question ... the scripts that you are including in your page...@JaydipsinhParmar

Comment: jquery-1.6.4.min.js,noconflict.js,jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js

Comment: @JaydipsinhParmar...just see in console fancybox and jquery file is loading correctly or not and try using $.noconflict as written in my answer just visit link given...

Comment: @JaydipsinhParmar...the problem in your case can be one of above listed problems just resolve these issues...